# Rails form view with a send button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionview, actionviewhelper

I have a form generated by scaffold in my _form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @survey do |f| %>

  <%= f.label :name %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <%= f.submit "Send", class: "btn btn-red span3" %>

<% end %>
```

my submit input produces:

```
<input class="btn btn-red span3" name="commit" type="submit" value="Send">
```

I want to produce a button instead a input. Like this:

```
<button class="btn btn-red span3" name="commit" type="submit">Send</button>
```

Any tip?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered a simple way

```
<%= button_tag "Send", class: "btn btn-red span3", name: "commit" %>
```

produces:

```
<button class="btn btn-red span3" name="commit" type="submit">Send</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= content_tag :button, type: :submit, class: "btn btn-red span3" do %>
   Send
<% end %>
```

Produces following HTML

```
<button class="btn btn-red span3" type="submit">
   Send
</button>
```